# Converting Points to Triangle_strip in geometry shader, how to pass UV's

Tags: opengl

I'm currently trying to pass points into a custom wrote sprite batcher, right now I have it so the points get the position and use the dimensions to create a triangle strip of a quad. my question though is if the geometry shader gets a single point then how do I pass around texture coordinates to the fragment shader?

I'm also trying to think about texture aliasing so the texture coordinates might not always be 0 to 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you emit 4 unique vertices right? Just assign each of the corners you emit in the geometry shader a different coordinate in the range [**0.0**,**1.0**] where `(0,0)` is the bottom-left of the image and `(1,1)` is the top-right.

#### Consider the following Geometry Shader:

```c
#version 330

layout (points) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 4) out;

out vec2 tex_coord;

void main (void) {
  const vec2 coordinates [] = vec2 [] (vec2 (0.0f, 0.0f),
                                       vec2 (1.0f, 0.0f),
                                       vec2 (1.0f, 1.0f),
                                       vec2 (0.0f, 1.0f));

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    gl_Position = gl_in [0].gl_Position + vec4 (coordinates [i], 0.0f, 0.0f);
    tex_coord   =                               coordinates [i];
    EmitVertex ();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware that you could pass new texture coordinates though the geometry shader, I thought it was only vertices with gl_Position.

Comment: @JoshuaWaring: No, you can create up to `gl_MaxGeometryOutputComponents` (**128** _minimum_) user-defined outputs for a geometry shader. That number is in terms of scalar components, so a `vec2` output in a geometry shader counts as **2** against that limit. Also keep in mind that any output you do not write to between calls to `EmitVertex (...)` will have undefined value (so if you had some output that was constant for all vertices, you would still have to write it in each iteration of that loop).